# What to do after installing Update 1 to TFS 2015 fails

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I've installed update 1 to our TFS 2015 and I'm forced to run the configuration wizard again, but I don't know which option is correct. I tried all of them but neither seems to work. Is there a tfsconfig command which allows me to do it via powershell?

Update: When trying to run the configuration wizard I receive the following error message
TF254043: The readiness checks could not start. For more information, see the following log file

Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed

```
at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.WebBindingInfo.AsUri()
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.ApplicationTierPlan.GenerateConfigurationPlan(TargetEnvironment env, ActivityInputs inputs, ActivityContext context)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.Engine.AdminActivity.GeneratePlans()
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.Console.Models.BaseWizardViewModel.StartVerification()
```

I've created a case with the microsoft support and they're working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the following answer from microsoft which can be found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f816fed0-a5c9-47b9-aace-a89854f6bd0b/tfs-2015-failes-to-upgrade-to-update-1)

In TFS 2015 you had an SSL binding with host name set to *. This is a valid binding, but unfortunately TFS does not handle this value correctly.

To workaround the issue, you can replace

<_x003C_Host_x003E_k__BackingField>*

with

<_x003C_Host_x003E_k__BackingField>

In the C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Team Foundation\Configuration\SavedSettings\ApplicationTier\ApplicationTierSettings.xml.

After changing the given config value the upgrade wizard ran through without any issues and I could manually set the SSL binding to *.

Answer (score 7):

If I remember right, there should be an upgrade option in the config wizard which you should be choosing.

Comment: The upgrade option pops automatically if you wait for the spinner on the first page to finish.

Comment: I'm receiving the following error message TF254043 hostname couldn't be resolved. Thanks but there seems to be an other error.

Comment: @Andreas, please provide the detailed information about on which step you get the TF254043 or other error message.

Comment: @Vicky-MSFT I've updated the original question. The error occures right when the readiness checks should start, after all the settings for the upgrade wizard are confirmed.